# How to access twitter moment API

Tags: twitter

I can embed one twitter moment into my website, I am curious, if Twitter offers any public moment api (similar to their search api) so I can automatically get their their top 4 twitter moments each day

```html
//This is i used their oembed to get one moment, if I know the id

<script sync src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
twttr.widgets.createMoment(
  '650667182356082688',
  document.getElementById('widget-content-twitter'),
  {
    limit: 1
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no public API endpoints for Moments at this time.